# how do I know which button is being pressed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a basic example of a menu with buttons, it's a questionnaire that asks simple questions and adds the amount of score, for that I call a method and call it from the onpressed.

The problem is that each button is not independent and they all have in common the same method (answerQuestion), which is to pass this function as anonymous.

answerQuestion have 2 parametres, the first is the score and the second is the name of botton.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'answer.dart';
import 'question.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final Function answerQuestion;

  Quiz({
    @required this.questions,
    @required this.questionIndex,
    @required this.answerQuestion,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          questions[questionIndex]['question'],
        ),
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((answer) {
          return Answer(() => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text']);
        })
      ],
    );
  }
}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './question.dart';
import './answer.dart';
import 'quiz.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _questionIndex = 0;
  var totalScore = 0;

  void _answerQuestion(int score) {
    print('Boton pulsado ');
    totalScore = totalScore + score;

    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
      print(_questionIndex);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      {
        'question': 'what is your favourite color',
        'answers': [
          {'text':'Black', 'score': 5},
          {'text':'White', 'score': 10},
          {'text':'Green', 'score': 15},
          {'text':'Blue', 'score': 20}
          ]
      },
      {
        'question': 'what is your favourite song',
        'answers': [
          {'text':'sdfdsf', 'score': 5},
          {'text':'asdas', 'score': 10},
          {'text':'tyu', 'score': 20},
          {'text':'Blwerack', 'score': 25}
          ]
      },
      {
        'question': 'what is your favourite food',
        'answers': [
          {'text':'macarrones', 'score': 5},
          {'text':'espaguetis', 'score': 10},
          {'text':'atun', 'score': 15},
          {'text':'albondigas', 'score': 20}
          ]
      }
    ];

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: 2 < 3 ? Quiz(answerQuestion: _answerQuestion, questionIndex: _questionIndex, questions: questions, ) : Center(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought about creating a list of buttons and then adding the parameter name in the call function but I don't know if this is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<FlatButton> buttons = [
FlatButton(
onPressed: () => onButtonPressed(0),
child: Text('Botón 1'),
),
FlatButton(
onPressed: () => onButtonPressed(1),
child: Text('Botón 2'),
),
FlatButton(
onPressed: () => onButtonPressed(2),
child: Text('Botón 3'),
),
];

void onButtonPressed(int buttonId) {
if (buttonId == 0) {
// El botón 1 ha sido pulsado
} else if (buttonId == 1) {
// El botón 2 ha sido pulsado
} else if (buttonId == 2) {
// El botón 3 ha sido pulsado
}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use callback method and try to update your flutter sdk